# Java Regular expression exclude special characters

Tags: java

I have to validate a String to check if it contains a special character or not. This string may contain any number and words ( including unicode, ie: à, â,ô .. ) but should not accept any special characters ( ie: !,@,#,%,^ ... )

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: English is just fine, but your effort is not.  What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This character class

```
[\p{L}\p{No}\p{Space}]
```

will include all characters which Unicode declares as either "letters", "numbers", or "whitespace characters". If you want to match a string against such a character class, you would write the following:

```
input.matches("[\\p{L}\\p{No}\\p{Space}]+")
```

For future reference, I have extracted all this information from the [`java.util.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. You should refer to that page for all your future interest in the Java regular expressions.

Comment: [\p{L}\p{No}\p{Space}] It's works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[\\p{L}\\s]+`. as example. This will remove special characters.

```
   Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\s]+");
    Matcher m=p.matcher("hissd@");
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(0));//
    }
```